# Can you use the same SD card on 2 different Pi's

Tags: sd-card, pi-2

Im looking at using 4-5 Pi 2 in the house front rooms bedrooms etc

What I was wondering is if I take out my current setup and put into a brand new Pi 2 would it boot up just the same?

Comment: Yep, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks so I could just clone the SD card and have all 5 with same setup?

Comment: Yes. You might need to modify individual configs such as static IPs or something which might lead to network conflicts ie, you can't have the same IP on all 5 RPi operating on the same network. Other than that, it works without any problem since there is no binding between  an RPi and SD card as such.

Comment: You will also need to regenerate the SSH keys to avoid conflicts.

Comment: thanks a lot its all new to me, was also looking at a dual boot but maybe im getting too far ahead of myself?

Comment: @SteveRobillard In fact I disagree. Provided `hostname` is unique there is no problem having identical keys. In fact I find it desirable, as I regularly swap cards between Pi, it causes problems with hosts if the same IP address (based on MAC) is used with a different key. I have been using identical host keys on all my PI, running different distributions for 2 yesrs.

Comment: @millways, that may well work  but it will result in a security warning when connecting via SSH and if using things which rely on SSH for communication (puppet, fabric etc.) can cause bigger issues. It also abuses the idea of trust inherent in SSH

Comment: @SteveRobillard I understand your comment, and would not do so in a wider environment. Unfortunately the current networking protocols do not work in an environment where it is possible (and routine) to totally swap environment between hardware. I have 7 SD and 3 Pi, which get swapped often. Ideally I would have host keys tied to machine i.e. MAC, but this is much more complex. On a local network there is no security issue.

Comment: @Milliways saying that "there is no security issue" that makes several assumptions about the network where these Pis will be deployed and how they will be used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can (I routinely do this). You should ensure that each is unique if on the same network. If using (the default) DHCP the IP addresses will be. It is also desirable to ensure `hostname` is unique. I use the following script (once only) to set this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to set Pi hostname based on MAC (or Serial number)
# 2017-08-18
# This script should be run as root (or with sudo) to change names
# If run by a user it will report changes, but will NOT implement them
# Works for PiB (all models), Pi2, Pi3, PiZeroW with on board networking
# PiA models will set a unique Name based on Serial number

PDIR="$(dirname "$0")"  # directory containing script
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)
# Find MAC of eth0, or if not exist wlan0
if [ -e /sys/class/net/eth0 ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address)
elif [ -e /sys/class/net/enx* ]; then
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/enx*/address)
else
    MAC=$(cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address)
fi

# NOTE the last 6 bytes of MAC and CPUID are identical
CPUID=$(awk '/Serial/ {print $3}' /proc/cpuinfo | sed 's/^0*//')
echo "Current Name" $CURRENT_HOSTNAME
echo "MAC" $MAC
# If you want to specify hostnames create a file PiNames.txt with MAC hostname list e.g.
# b8:27:eb:01:02:03 MyPi
# If not found a unique Name based on Serial number will be set
NEW_HOSTNAME=$(awk /$MAC/' {print $2}' $PDIR"/PiNames.txt")
echo "Name found" $NEW_HOSTNAME
if [ $NEW_HOSTNAME == "" ]; then
    NEW_HOSTNAME="pi"$CPUID
fi

if [ $NEW_HOSTNAME = $CURRENT_HOSTNAME ]; then
    echo "Name already set"
else
    echo "Setting Name" $NEW_HOSTNAME
    echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
    sed -i "/127.0.1.1/s/$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/$NEW_HOSTNAME/" /etc/hosts
fi
```

Comment: wow that's gone over my head, what is the host name? my first PI i just set up i put "Front Room" as a name this was setup using openelec off noobs

Comment: `hostname` is by default `raspberrypi`. It can be changed through `raspi-config` and displayed by entering `hostname`. This is used for many purposes to identify systems e.g. `ssh`. You don't have to use the script, this can be set manually, but I do it so often, it was easier to automate. By "gone over my head" I presume you mean the script. Like many system scripts, you don't have to understand how they work (this can often be cryptic). Apart from the sed and awk this is pretty ordinary `bash` scripting.

Answer (score -1):

It is not compatible backwards even with the same generation. For example you cannot use SD card from Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 1 to Rev 2, it will not work, screen well be just black, but from Rev 2 you can use it in Rev 1.

Comment: If you are trying to claim that there were two versions of the OS distributed for the 1B, you are wrong, as is this claim in general.  The SoC on the rev. 1 and 2 is the same, and it is actually the same as the one used on the plain Zero, and I'd bet the latest RpiOS image will still run on all of these. Put another way: *"It is not compatible backwards even with the same generation"* -> Also just plain wrong.  What it is is not forward compatible across the different SoCs (eg., an un-updated image from 2015 could not be run on a Pi 4).